# d3 stacked bar with bars don't update in a transition

Tags: d3.js, transition, stacked-chart

In sequence of this problem ([d3 show labels only for ticks with data in a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299330/d3-show-labels-only-for-ticks-with-data-in-a-bar-chart)) I've applied a transition to change the data of a stacked bar chart using D3.

My axes have a perfect transition and modification for this new dataSet, but the horizontal bars are still untouched. 
I've tried this solution from Lars ([d3.js bar charts transitioning between multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410053/d3-js-bar-charts-transitioning-between-multiple-csv-files)) but I still can see the bars changed.

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ocks-org do-not-copy">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div><button class="btn btn-mini" id="backButton" onclick="updateData();">Update</button></div>
<div id="timeLine"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var timeline;

var margin = {
    top : 20,
    right : 10,
    bottom : 60,
    left : 80
},
width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([height, 0], 0.1);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#1f77b4", "#2ca02c", "#E53524"]);
//var color = d3.scale.category10()

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"))
    .ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

timeline = d3.select("#timeLine").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

    var dataSet;

dataSet = [{
        "Date" : "2014-01",
        "insert" : "2",
        "remove" : "17",
        "updates" : "27"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2014-02",
        "insert" : "27",
        "remove" : "127",
        "updates" : "47"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2014-03",
        "insert" : "227",
        "remove" : "17",
        "updates" : "42"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2014-04",
        "insert" : "0",
        "remove" : "0",
        "updates" : "0"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2014-05",
        "insert" : "127",
        "remove" : "1",
        "updates" : "423"
    },
];
color.domain(d3.keys(dataSet[0]).filter(function (key) {
        return key !== "Date";
    }));

dataSet.forEach(function (d) {
    var x0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function (name) {
            return {
                name : name,
                x0 : x0,
                x1 : x0 += +d[name]
            };
        });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].x1;
});

yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    var val = 0;
    dataSet.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.Date == d)
            val = item.total;
    });
    return val == 0 ? "" : d;
});

y.domain(dataSet.map(function (d) {
        return d.Date;
    }));

x.domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function (d) {
            return (d.total + 5);
        })]);

timeline.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("x", 1)
.attr("dx", "42em")
.attr("dy", "3em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Operations");

timeline.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);

var layer = timeline.selectAll(".state")
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(0," + y(d.Date) + ")";
    });

var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function (d) {
        return d.ages;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
        return y(d.Date);
    })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.name);
    });

rect.transition()
.duration(600)
.delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 300;
})
.attr("width", function (d) {
    return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
})
.attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.x0);
});

function updateData() {

    dataSet = [{
        "Date" : "2014-11",
        "insert" : "27",
        "remove" : "1723",
        "updates" : "7"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2014-12",
        "insert" : "237",
        "remove" : "12",
        "updates" : "433"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2015-03",
        "insert" : "22",
        "remove" : "172",
        "updates" : "423"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2015-05",
        "insert" : "17",
        "remove" : "122",
        "updates" : "42"
    }, {
        "Date" : "2015-04",
        "insert" : "0",
        "remove" : "0",
        "updates" : "0"
    }
];

dataSet.forEach(function (d) {
    var x0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function (name) {
            return {
                name : name,
                x0 : x0,
                x1 : x0 += +d[name]
            };
        });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].x1;
});

yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
    var val = 0;
    dataSet.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.Date == d)
            val = item.total;
    });
    return val == 0 ? "" : d;
});

y.domain(dataSet.map(function (d) {
        return d.Date;
    }));

x.domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function (d) {
            return (d.total + 5);
        })]);

// Make the changes
var transition = timeline.transition().duration(750),
delay = function (d, i) {
    return i * 50;
};

// update bars
//var teste = timeline.selectAll(".state").data(dataSet);
var layer = timeline.selectAll(".state").data(dataSet).enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(0," + y(d.Date) + ")";
    });

var sel = layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function (d) {
        return d.ages;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
        return y(d.Date);
    })
    //.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.name);
    });

//remove bars no longer present - DON'T WORK
//sel.exit().remove();

sel.transition()
.duration(600)
.delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 300;
})
.attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.x0);
}).attr("width", function (d) {
    return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
})
.attr('y', function (d, i) {
    return y(d.Date);
})
.attr("height", y.rangeBand());

transition.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
.call(yAxis);

transition.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
.call(xAxis);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Filipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's skip the organization of the code. 
The main error is that you try to access a variable not defined. 
First when you build the stacked bars, you do that:

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function (d) {
    return d.ages;
})
```

that associate to each rect the values in "d.ages", and so you can access the "d.x0" and "d.x1". In the update function you try to access directly the "d.x0" and "d.x1" that don't exist since they are in the ages element.

Your dataset item in the main function:

```
Object {name: "insert", x0: 0, x1: 2}
```

Your dataset item in the update function:

```
Object {Date: "2015-03", insert: "22", remove: "172", updates: "423", ages: Array[3]…}
```

and then in ages:

```
ages: Array[3]
      0: Object
         name: "insert"
         x0: 0
         x1: 22
......................
```

Comment: Hi Francesco, Thanks for your help. I've updates my code and Ia can see the new bars. But the old one are still in the chart. The sel.exit().remove(); in my update function doesn't do the work that supposed to do.

Comment: If you update the code, I could have a look on it :)

Comment: Ok, solved, it is not the proper solution, but how it is designed your chart it is the best, you fill find it out here -> http://jsfiddle.net/g822u058/
I added a class ('first') when you draw the bars the first time and a class ("update") when you update them, then, each time you call the update function, the first two instruction just delete the old bars.

Comment: Hi Francesco, It works! But I made some changes: we don't need this two new classes. Just put this at the beginning of the update function: d3.selectAll('.rect').remove();. Just remove all bars before we construct others. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, even better. My pleasure @milheiros ;)